# UIPickerView data problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

All,

I have an external class file like :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalVars : NSObject {
    NSArray *alllocationsID;
    NSArray *alllocationsCity;
}


@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *alllocationsID;
@property(nonatomic, copy)  NSArray *alllocationsCity;


@end
```

and then i get data like this and put it in the array :

```
GlobalVars *Global = [[GlobalVars alloc] init];
        Global.alllocationsID = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"ID"];
        Global.alllocationsCity = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"%@", Global.alllocationsCity);
        NSLog(@"%@",Global.alllocationsID);
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)Global.alllocationsID.count);
```

that brings in the correct amount of .count which is 14, so it gets the data from the global class file.

but in my numberofRowsinCompent the global.allocationsID.count brings in 0, no wonder why the picker view doesn't show!

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {


    GlobalVars *Global = [[GlobalVars alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)Global.alllocationsID.count);

    NSInteger numRows = Global.alllocationsID.count;

    return numRows;
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Did you check your spell *allocationsID* is different from *alllocationsID*

Answer (score 0):

In `numberofRowsinComponent` you should not allocate GlobalVars.

So in `.h`

```
GlobalVars *Global;
```

then in `.m`

```
Global = [[GlobalVars alloc] init];
Global.alllocationsID = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"ID"];
Global.alllocationsCity = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@", Global.alllocationsCity);
NSLog(@"%@",Global.alllocationsID);
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)Global.alllocationsID.count);
```

then in `numberofRowinComponent`

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)Global.alllocationsID.count);

    NSInteger numRows = Global.alllocationsID.count;

    return numRows;
 }
```

Comment: I understand what your saying but Global = [[GlobalVars alloc] init] where does that need to be assigned , in the view did load or in the method where the data is captured from the database (i.e. the function above - valueforkey etc ?

Comment: viewdidload is the better one.

Comment: ok so I add Global = [[GlobalVars alloc] init]; to the viewdidload and within the method above (the NSLogs get null) and the numberofrowsincomponent is still null. but if i add Global= [[GlobalVats alloc] init] to the database retrieval function then the NSLOGS come up as the correct count but still numberofrowsincompontent is still null.. help :)

Comment: this is my .h@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    GlobalVars *Global;
}

Comment: what about your GlobalVars.m file?

Comment: where abouts in the globalvars.m file ?

Comment: have u did anything in GlobalVars.m file? also try with property for `GlobalVars *Global;`

Comment: Nope GlobalVars.m is blank

Comment: also try with property for GlobalVars *Global;

Comment: in GlobalVars.m, - (id)init { if ((self = [super init])) { self.alllocationsCity = [NSArray array]; self.alllocationsID = [NSArray array]; } return self; }